# pg_dump while inserting data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, psql, pg-dump, dump

I need to dump some tables of my postgres database and I am scared of getting inconsistent data.The database is verly large and the dump lasts some minutes.
On my research I found a command to dump single tables:

```
pg_dump --column-inserts -a -t exampleTable -t exampleTable 2> /tmp/myTables.sql
```

The next problem is that while dumping new data will be inserted in the tables. Is it correct that data which are inserted while dumping are ignored? Especially if I ru the command like the example? Is there anything special to do for dumping?

Or can I really run the pg_dump command and everything is fine? Does anyone have an easy way to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how you run `pg_dump`, it will always use a single `REPEATABLE READ READ ONLY` transaction to read the data, so it will see a consistent snapshot of the data from the time that the backup started.

So as long as you dump all the data you need with a single `pg_dump` command, you will be safe from data inconsistencies.

If you want a quote from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html):

> It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently.